# Difference between Matrix formed by List comprehensions and multiplying list element?

Tags: python, math, matrix

I am trying to change diagonal elements of a null matrix to `1`. 
So when I formed a matrix by using multiplying list elements  `[ [ 0 ] * 4 ] * 4` and changed its Diagonal elements to `1`, It changed all elements to `1`.
But when I formed a matrix by using List comprehensions and changed its Diagonal elements to `1`, It worked correctly. Below is the implementations mentioned above:

```
mat1 = [ [ 0 for i in range(4) ]  for j in range( 4 ) ]   #  Using List Comprehensions
mat2 = [ [ 0 ] * 4 ] * 4                                              # Using multiplying list elements


print( mat1 == mat2 )                         # True

for i in range(4):
    mat1[ i ][ i ]=1                             # mat1 =  [ [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1] ]
    mat2[ i ][ i ]=1                             # mat2 =  [ [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1] ]
```

Where I am doing wrong while using matrix formed by multiplying list elements? 
Or I am misleading some concepts?

Any explanation is appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather interesting.

```
mat1 = [ [ 0 for i in range(4) ]  for j in range( 4 ) ]   #  Using List Comprehensions
mat2 = [ [ 0 ] * 4 ] * 4                                              # Using multiplying list elements


print( mat1 == mat2 )                         # True
print( mat1 is mat2 )                         # False

for i in range(4):
    mat1[ i ][ i ]=1                             # mat1 =  [ [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1] ]
    mat2[ i ][ i ]=1
```

As we can see from the simple test of `print(mat1 is mat2)` which returned `False` shows that the variables point to different objects. However `print(mat1 == mat2)` returns `True` which occurs if the objects referred to by the variables are equal. Hence in this case, the variables are equal. However the objects are different.

As you can see from `mat1`, you are actually looping in a nested loop, however for `mat2` you are actually referencing to the same array of `[0]`.

You can basically tell if you multiply arrays by doing the following,

```
mat1 = [1,2,3]
mat2 = mat1*2
print(mat2)

# outputs
[1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Comment: Oof, it's rough to lose your win to a duplicate </3

Comment: @SamuelWillems Theres no "win" or "lose" in stackoverflow! I just hope that everyone learns something through this site :)

Comment: Haha, yea of course

Answer (score 1):

This is actually because `mat2` contains 4 references to the same list of 4 elements. In every step of your loop you are setting a value in the same list.

When you say `[0, 0, 0, 0] * 4` you are just creating a list which contains the same list four times. This means there are only two actual lists in play.

When you say `[[0, 0, 0, 0] for i in [0, 1, 2, 3]]` you create a new list with every iteration. This means there are five actual lists in play.

The following snippet should visualize it:

```
m1 = [[0 for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]
m2 = [[0] * 4] * 4

for i in range(4):
    m1[i][i] = 1
    m2[i][i] = 1

    print('m1 at i={}: {}'.format(i, m1))
    print('m2 at i={}: {}'.format(i, m2))
    print('')
```

outputs:

```
m1 at i=0: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
m2 at i=0: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]

m1 at i=1: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
m2 at i=1: [[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]

m1 at i=2: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
m2 at i=2: [[1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]]

m1 at i=3: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
m2 at i=3: [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```